# ArrayFormula to calculate previous rows

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas

I have 3 sheets:

- Sheet1 - list of transactions (Account, Credit, Debit, Date)
- Sheet2 - list of transactions (Account, Credit, Debit, Date)
- Sheet3 (I plan to lock it) - combined list of transactions, sorted by Date

Sheet3 looks like:
[image]

I need to add 1 more column to Sheet3 to count current balance for certain row to be like:
[image]

I'm able to do this with formula:

```
=SUM(FILTER($B$2:$B$8, ROW($A$2:$A$8) <= ROW($A2), A$2:A$8=$A2)) - SUM(FILTER($C$2:$C$8, ROW($A$2:$A$8) <= ROW($A2), A$2:A$8=$A2))
```

But this one I need continuously drag down.

Question: Is there way convert this formula to ArrayFormula, to avoid dragging

Comment: There is no way to force arrayformula to function like an array mapping function. Without that, you basically need, for each row, a `true`/`false` array for account name, a `true`/`false` array for whether a row is above or below and then multiple (dot product) to array of to date summed values. That's why it is computationally inefficient..

Comment: btw, your current formula can be made a lot simpler: `=sum(filter(B$2:B2-C$2:C2,A$2:A2=A2))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Sheet3 row 1, put your headers.

In `Sheet3!A2`, put

```
=sort({filter(Sheet1!A2:D,not(isblank(Sheet1!A2:A)));filter(Sheet2!A2:D,not(isblank(Sheet2!A2:A))),4,true)
```

In `Sheet3!E2`, put

```
=mmult(transpose(arrayformula(arrayformula(array_constrain(A2:A,counta(A2:A),1)=transpose(array_constrain(A2:A,counta(A2:A),1)))
                              *arrayformula(array_constrain(row(A2:A),counta(A2:A),1)<=transpose(array_constrain(row(A2:A),counta(A2:A),1))))),
       arrayformula(array_constrain(B2:B,counta(A2:A),1)-array_constrain(C2:C,counta(A2:A),1))
```

---

To see why, let's temporarily remove the `array_constrain(...,counta(...),1)` wrappings, which is meant to auto detect the last data row:

```
=mmult(transpose(arrayformula(arrayformula(A2:A9=transpose(A2:A9))
                 *arrayformula(row(A2:A9)<=transpose(row(A2:A9))))),
       arrayformula(B2:B9-C2:C9))
```

`arrayformula(B2:B9-C2:C9)` are the running sums of column B - column C (ie. credit - debit). It is a column vector with the length of your data size.

We want to, **for each row**, 1) filter this vector by comparison to column A (ie. account name) & 2) filter this vector by whether the running sums are below or above the row in question.

`arrayformula(A2:A9=transpose(A2:A9))` does 1). `arrayformula(row(A2:A9)<=transpose(row(A2:A9)))` does 2).

We want elementwise product between the 2 matrices in order to compose the filter. Hence, `arrayformula(...*...)`.

The columns of our filters are meant to be applied to the running sums. To use matrix multiplication, we can keep the column vector of running sums as the post-multiplier; and transpose the filter matrix as pre-multiplier so that the rows of the transposed matrix are multiplied (ie. applied) to the running sums. Hence, `mmult(transpose(...),...)`.

Add back the `array_constrain` trick. And we are done.

Feel free to experiment with alternate placings of `arrayformula`. But remember to keep the `()` brackets wherever you omit `arrayformula`. Example:

```
=arrayformula(mmult(transpose(((array_constrain(A2:A,counta(A2:A),1)=transpose(array_constrain(A2:A,counta(A2:A),1)))
                                *(array_constrain(row(A2:A),counta(A2:A),1)<=transpose(array_constrain(row(A2:A),counta(A2:A),1))))),
                    (array_constrain(B2:B,counta(A2:A),1)-array_constrain(C2:C,counta(A2:A),1))))
```

---

Nonetheless, the 1 formula solution is computationally **in**efficient compared to individually spread formula per cell. That is because, without mutating the formula per row, we are forced to compute the filters as full n-by-n matrices where n is your data size.

Whereas, if in E2 we put `=sum(filter(B$2:B2-C$2:C2,A$2:A2=A2))` and spread to the end by double right-clicking the square on bottom right when you select E2, the formula mutates per row, saving the row index comparison entirely, and also cutting the comparison to column A logarithmically.

Granted, we probably shouldn't rely on Google Sheet for a large database (e.g. >100k entries). But even for thousands of entries, if you square the amount of computations required, getting the results in browser becomes impractically slow well before one may expect.

Comment: Thanks for great explanation, I tried to play with it, but still it is making sheet slow, seems best way is to drag formula till end

Answer (score 2):

In G2 on sheet 3 I entered

```
=ArrayFormula(if(A2:A="",,mmult((A2:A=transpose(A2:A))*(row(A2:A)>= TRANSPOSE(row(A2:A)))*(transpose(B2:B)-transpose(C2:C)),row(A2:A)^0)))
```

See if that works for you?

Comment: It is working fine, but for some reason my complete real sheet started to work very slow and working fine when I delete this formula.

Comment: It's quite a resource hungry formula. If you have a lot of empty rows try removing those and see if it works better then. I'll see if I can come up with an alternative.

Comment: Yes, you're right, even if I add 1000 rows to example doc, it is starting to work slow there also