# Google Sheet Filter - exclude the first match associated to a column

Tags: google-sheets, filter

I have this Google Sheet that I ran a Filter in E2 to show all other stock-id's associated with each ID (in column A). What I want to achieve is to exclude in the result the data in the 1st match (in column F) because that is already in the stock-id column. I am using this formula FILTER(E1:E,A1:A=A2) that I just Transpose.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Hp3TmTPlUTEkrhN3iEMLtlMbDZoapvJb5T8oYr2SmB0

Thank you for your help.

Comment: You mean filter in F2? And you mean to exclude the data in E2? Try to define and show desired output in the examples when you ask questions please.

Comment: Aside, the match of the same row isn't the first match. You want to exclude a particular match (ie. from the same row), *not* the first match, right? (If so, please edit the tittle accordingly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In column F, put

```
=transpose(FILTER(E$2:E,A$2:A=A2,E$2:E<>E2))
```

and spread.

`filter()` can accept multiple conditions.

*btw, if you happen to be wondering how to make a single formula so you dont have to spread the formula, the better recommendation is: [don't](https://stackoverflow.com/q/73076501/3181104).*

Comment: Thank you so much this the one that we want to achieve .

Answer (score 2):

### Option 01

> Paste it in `F2` and drag it down

```
=IF(COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E1:E,A1:A=A2)))<=1,TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E1:E,A1:A=A2)),TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula(QUERY( {SORT( ArrayFormula(SORTN( { QUERY( {TRANSPOSE( { SEQUENCE(1,COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E1:E,A1:A=A2))),1,1); TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E1:E,A1:A=A2))})}, " Select Col1 "), QUERY( {TRANSPOSE( { SEQUENCE(1,COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E1:E,A1:A=A2))),1,1); TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E1:E,A1:A=A2))})}, " Select Col2 ") } ,IF(( COUNTA(QUERY( {TRANSPOSE( { SEQUENCE(1,COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E1:E,A1:A=A2))),1,1); TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E1:E,A1:A=A2))})}, " Select Col2 ")))<1,1,( COUNTA(QUERY( {TRANSPOSE( { SEQUENCE(1,COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E1:E,A1:A=A2))),1,1); TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E1:E,A1:A=A2))})}, " Select Col2 "))-1)),,1,0)),1,1)}, "  Select Col2"))))
```

### Option 02

> Paste it in `F2` and drag it down

```
=IF(COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E1:E,A1:A=A2)))<=1,TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E1:E,A1:A=A2)),TRANSPOSE(ArrayFormula(QUERY( {SORT( ArrayFormula(SORTN( { QUERY( {TRANSPOSE( { SEQUENCE(1,COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E1:E,A1:A=A2))),1,1); TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E1:E,A1:A=A2))})}, " Select Col1 "), QUERY( {TRANSPOSE( { SEQUENCE(1,COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E1:E,A1:A=A2))),1,1); TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E1:E,A1:A=A2))})}, " Select Col2 ") } ,IF(( COUNTA(QUERY( {TRANSPOSE( { SEQUENCE(1,COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E1:E,A1:A=A2))),1,1); TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E1:E,A1:A=A2))})}, " Select Col2 ")))<1,1,( COUNTA(QUERY( {TRANSPOSE( { SEQUENCE(1,COUNTA(TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E1:E,A1:A=A2))),1,1); TRANSPOSE(FILTER(E1:E,A1:A=A2))})}, " Select Col2 "))-1)),,1,0)),1,1)}, "  Select Col2"))))
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To exclude the *first match* you get from `filter()`, use `query()`, like this:

`=transpose( iferror( query( filter(E$2:E, A$2:A = A2), "offset 1", 0 ) ) )`

But apparently what the OP really needs is not that. To exclude a value that is *already present* in the same row, add another criteria in the `filter()` instead. See the [other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73094039/13045193).